# Splitting a row into multiple rows to reflect a change in a column (keeping all column values the same but one)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I have a dataframe where in one of the columns two values are contained. They are separated by white space.
['U.N.Region']['North West'] into two rows so that I would have North and East. Like this[image]

Comment: why is only one `North East` splitted and not the one on row 3 and why not `North West` at row 4?

Comment: Just that one needs to be split up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full DataFrame approach

```py
# Build your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Province': ['Badakhshan', 'Badghis', 'Baghlan', 'Balkh', 'Kapisa'],
   'Centers': ['Fayzabad', 'QalaNaw', 'PuliKhumri', 'MazarSharif', 'MahmudRaqi'],
   'Region': ['North East', 'West', 'North East', 'North West', 'Center'] 
})

# Split one column
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.Region.str.split(' ').tolist(), index=[df.Province, df.Centers]).stack()

# Reset indices
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, 'Province', 'Centers'])

# Rename columns if you want to
new_df.columns = ['Province', 'Centers', 'Regions']

# Print new DataFrame
>>>new_df
     Province      Centers Regions
0  Badakhshan     Fayzabad   North
1  Badakhshan     Fayzabad    East
2     Badghis      QalaNaw    West
3     Baghlan   PuliKhumri   North
4     Baghlan   PuliKhumri    East
5       Balkh  MazarSharif   North
6       Balkh  MazarSharif    West
7      Kapisa   MahmudRaqi  Center
```

Only one row approach

```py
# Build your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Province': ['Badakhshan', 'Badghis', 'Baghlan', 'Balkh', 'Kapisa'],
   'Centers': ['Fayzabad', 'QalaNaw', 'PuliKhumri', 'MazarSharif', 'MahmudRaqi'],
   'Region': ['North East', 'West', 'North East', 'North West', 'Center'] 
})

# Split one row only
new_list = df[df.Province=='Badakhshan'].Region.str.split(' ')[0]

# Replace to that location
df.loc[0, 'Region'] = new_list

# Explode column
df = df.explode('Region')

# Reindex
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Print new DataFrame
>>>df
     Province      Centers      Region
0  Badakhshan     Fayzabad       North
1  Badakhshan     Fayzabad        East
2     Badghis      QalaNaw        West
3     Baghlan   PuliKhumri  North East
4       Balkh  MazarSharif  North West
5      Kapisa   MahmudRaqi      Center
```

Just as tip, adapt what you can find and not hope to get exact solutions. And please add code snippets and tell us what you already tried to do.

Comment: That's for the whole columns though